# How can I set PyPI index URL in PyCharm Community 2022.3? The "Manage Repositories" button was removed in this version

Tags: python, pycharm

I've just upgrade my PyCharm Community from 2020.3 to 2022.3. I used to set a private PyPI index-url in PyCharm via File --> Setting --> Porject: xxx --> Python Interpreter --> "plus" sign --> Manage Repositories. But the button was removed from PyCharm Community 2022.3.

Old version of PyCharm with "Manage Repositories" button:
[image]

New 2022.3 version of PyCharm Community without "Manage Repositories" button:
[image]

I googled the case but can't get an answer, it seems that most of the articles assume that the "Manage Repositories" button still exists. I searched "manage", "repositor" in PyCharm Settings searching box, but no such configuration was found. I thought "Settings Repository" plug-in is what I want, but it seems that this plug-in is about sharing IDE settings rather than PyPI index-url.

I'm using PyCharm on Windows platform, the detail version information is:

PyCharm 2022.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-223.7571.203, built on November 30, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation

Comment: I see the same thing doing the same upgrade, but I am using the professional version.  I'll file a support ticket with JetBrains and see what they say.

Answer (score 5):

It has moved to `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Python Packages`

[image]